# Is java sdk version in android library affects java version of the project using it?

Tags: android, sdk, java-8

I have my own android library (sdk) and i am considering moving to Java 8. 
i don't see any documentation about how it affects the customers that use my sdk. Can it cause problems ? do they need to change something in their code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile your library with Java 8 by using e.g. in the `build.gradle`

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

then any android project below Java 8 will not work with your sdk. Even if you do not use any Java 8 Methods. This will probably change with Android Studio 3.0 where Java 8 will be shipped built-in.

As of now Java 8 is no supported below Android Studio < 3.0 - even with the deprecated jack toolchain.